# Error in Ajax Combobox sorting

Tags: ajax, c#-4.0, sorting, combobox

I had applied sorting in the ajax combobox and things are working fine except one special case in one of my combobox:
All the items are displayed in sorted(order by Names) below -- Select --, but one item is displayed above select.
I have checked the Id as well and the Id is also '1388' where the Id of --Select -- is '0'.

Can anyone predict what can be the reason?
aspx code:

```
<ajax:ComboBox ID="LendersCmbx" runat="server" Width="150px" CssClass="AquaStyle textfont"
                                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="LendersCmbx_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"
                                    DropDownStyle="DropDownList" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" CaseSensitive="false"
                                    ItemInsertLocation="OrdinalText">
                                </ajax:ComboBox>
```

My aspx.cs code:

```
 LendersCmbx.DataSource = LenBobj.FillLenders();
        LendersCmbx.DataTextField = "LenderName";
        LendersCmbx.DataValueField = "LenderId";
        LendersCmbx.DataBind();
```

My BL Code:

```
   public List<Lender> FillLenders()
    {
        return obj.GetLenders();
    }
```

and DAL Code:

```
 public List<Lender> GetLenders()
    {
        return context.Lenders.OrderBy(Lender=>Lender.LenderName).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Where does the "select" item come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question here as I jst found the solution:
There was a reason, we had spacing in that item in the starting only so that space was the reason that it was appearing first.
The select was the item which is displayed initially and it had an Id '0', but the item Raina-el-main was displayed as before R I had given a spacing by mistake.